# Msi installer works on one machine, not on another - browser issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, blazor, windows-services, webassembly

When I host asp.net core web application as windows service, I want records from db to be listed on landing page. It gets displayed on one machine but I get below exception in another machine. The same msi is used for installation in both the machines. I already tried reinstalling my browsers.

Exception in index.razor page.

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: ExpectedStartOfValueNotFound, < Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
blazor.webassembly.js:1  ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: ExpectedStartOfValueNotFound, < LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyApp.Shared.Item, MyApp.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
blazor.webassembly.js:1    Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, JsonReaderException ex)
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyApp.Shared.item, MyApp.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[List`1](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[List`1](JsonReaderState& readerState, Boolean isFinalBlock, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, JsonConverter converterBase)
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.<ReadAsync>d__20`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyApp.Shared.Item, MyApp.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.<ReadFromJsonAsyncCore>d__3`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyApp.Shared.Item, MyApp.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at MyApp.Client.Service.ItemService.GetItems()
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at MyApp.Client.Pages.Index.OnInitializedAsync() Exception caught..
```

Only difference I could see is the content type of web service call:

Machine that works returns content type as application/json.
Machine that does not work returns content type as below:

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1   Content-Type: text/html
```

Below file is where I get error:

Index.razor:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        items= await ItemService.GetItems() // error here
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught..", e); // error msg I have posted is caught here
    }   
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you log the value that’s trying to be parsed as Json, it might be an error message which will help you find the problem.

Comment: Please see my code under edited. This is where I get exception. May I know where you would like me to try logging the value.

Comment: The JSON error you're receiving when making a web service call is one I've run into before when it tries to parse the results but the results aren't a valid object because of an HTTP error I've ran into. You'll want to troubleshoot the response object you're getting back from the web service call. It probably is a 400-level or 500-level error, which can be due to a number of things depending on the exact response code.

Comment: A service use by default a System account which does not have an environment.  You need to create an account and start service using the account.  The account needs access to the database.  It is better to use a windows account for connecting to database with Integrated Security = True in connection string.  When debugging use SQL Server Management Studio.   The log files are in the explorer under Management.  Check the error logs which will give error why connection failed.  It will include the account that was used during failure.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will try following what you mentioned.

Comment: Your front end is returning a 200 because you are swallowing the exception in your try catch.  If I'm looking at that correctly, at Index.razor

Comment: I have got a partial solution to this problem. When I install msi in a different machine, It works fine. I get records displayed from DB. So it is a browser issue on my machine I have been trying.

Comment: Tried adding _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8") in itemService.cs. But still the browser not displaying DB records.

Comment: Thank you explaining the cause of my 200 status msg. That clears a lot.

Comment: Hi everyone. I was able to resolve the issue. By setting content-type and uninstalling the previous msi version manually, before installing the newer version helped.

Comment: Please type your answer as an answer to the issue, or give the information to the comment that helped you the most, so you do not lose the posted bounty.